# How to pass child state data to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I want to pass a string from a child component to its parent, which in turn will update the data passed to the child component. For example, when a `link` is clicked, change planet data to reflect new planet.

There are three components.

1. Parent
2. Middle-man
3. Child

#### Hierarchy

`Home => Navbar => ExpandedMenu`

### Parent Component

I have mapped each planet to an object called `planetData` from the json data. When a link is clicked, I want it to update the contents assigned to the planet passed.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "../../shared/components/Navbar/Navbar";
import MobileView from "../../home/components/MobileView/MobileView";
import TabletView from "../../home/components/TabletView/TabletView";
import DesktopView from "../../home/components/DesktopView/DesktopView";

import Page from "../../shared/interface/Page/Page";
import data from "../../db/data.json";

function Home() {
  // responds to events, changes active planet to represent current
  const [activePlanet, setActivePlanet] = useState(data[0]);


  // map each planet in json data to objects
  const planetData = {
    mercury: data[0],
    venus: data[1],
    earth: data[2],
    mars: data[3],
    jupiter: data[4],
    saturn: data[5],
    uranus: data[6],
    neptune: data[7],
  };

  // render complete page to document
  return (
    <Page>
      <Navbar />

      {/* Conditional rendering based on screen width */}
      {isDesktop && <DesktopView content={activePlanet} />}
      {isTablet && <TabletView content={activePlanet} />}
      {isMobile && <MobileView content={activePlanet} />}
    </Page>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

### Middle Component

Component is purely a middle man.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import HamburgerMenu from "../../../assets/icon-hamburger.svg";
import ExpandedMenu from "../ExpandedMenu/ExpandedMenu";
import NavMenu from "../NavMenu/NavMenu";

function Navbar() {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

  return (
    <nav>
      <NavMenu />
      <ExpandedMenu isToggled={isVisible} />
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

### Child Component

When a link is clicked, it updates the state to a string representing the planet.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import NavLink from "../NavLink/NavLink";
import Arrow from "../../../assets/icon-chevron.svg";

function ExpandedMenu({ isToggled }) {
  const [planet, setPlanet] = useState("Mercury");

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Mercury */}
      <div>
        <div>
          <NavLink
            clickAction={() => {
              setPlanet("Mercury");
            }}
          >
            Mercury
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <img src={Arrow} alt="arrow" />
      </div>

      {/* Venus */}
      <div>
        <div>
          <NavLink
            clickAction={() => {
              setPlanet("Venus");
            }}
          >
            Venus
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <img src={Arrow} alt="arrow" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ExpandedMenu;
```

Comment: You can keep the data in the Parent component and use a function to pass the props from the child to the Parent. This concept is called [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). You might try this to solve your problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67798302/react-js-pass-the-data-or-child-component-to-parent-component

Comment: Pass a callback fn from the parent component to your children component. And when you invoke the cb, pass the string as params.

Comment: I've managed to get the state info passed to the parent, but how would I go about re-rendering the content based on the string passed?